# Bash variable from within bash variable with text

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to echo a string into a file which has variables inside it along with plaintext. and use it later with a command but have the variable be interpreted. I have tried to use `eval` with limited success but then I cannot include characters such as <>

```
body=`cat ~/body`;

echo -e "${body}" >> message
```

`message` is later used in the following command

```
sendmail -f noreply@example.com $recipient < message;
```

If the contents of `message` are:

```
"Hello. The current epoch time is<br>
${EPOCHSECONDS}
"
```

I'd like the output to have the var interpreted and the body shown as

```
"Hello. The current epoch time is<br>
1662823014"
```

Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`envsubst` https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html should help you.

For example

```
$ cat message.txt
Hello. The current epoch time is
${EPOCHSECONDS}.

$ EPOCHSECONDS=1662823014

$ export EPOCHSECONDS

$ cat message.txt | envsubst
Hello. The current epoch time is
1662823014
```

Comment: Right, so like `envsubst < message | sendmail -f noreply@example.com $recipient`.

Comment: envsubst exists in git bash but does not exist in cygwin bash.

Comment: Notice that [`EPOCHSECONDS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-EPOCHSECONDS) is a special variable since Bash 5.0, and assignments to it are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, you can do this as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
body=$( cat ~/body )

##### Set Message Variables ##########################################
EPOCHSECONDS=1662823014

##### Replace Template Variables #####################################
final_message=$( eval echo \"${body}\" )

##### Do whatever you want with ${final_message} #####################
echo "Final Message: "
echo "${final_message}"
```